# jquery search all CSS with display inline-block

Tags: jquery, css

Is it possible to search the CSS by property:value instead of selector/attribute? Or would this need to be parsed via server script?

If it is possible I would plan to create a script which automatically adds the IE7 hack if the selector has: `display: inline-block` because I am fed up of writing `*display: inline;  zoom: 1;`

Comment: What hack do you need? HTML5 Shiv? Clearfix? There are many ways to implement these on IE without any hacks, now if you what you need is something more specific, you can use an IE conditional block with the IE-only style.

Comment: You should instead go for a CSS reset. or some other type of css sheet to correct this behaviour for you. having JS manipulate every inline-block DOM node will be much more expensive than having a conditional sheet or a reset for just IE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code should allow you to process something if the element is styled as inline-block.

```
$("body *").each(function (i) {
    if ($(this).css('display') == "inline-block") {
        //inline block - do what you need to do
        this.style.color = "blue";
        alert($(this).css('display'));            
    }
});
```

See the jsfiddle for working example http://jsfiddle.net/nevtn/

Here would be the entire script you need:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

if ($.browser.msie  && parseInt($.browser.version, 10) === 7) {
    $("body *").each(function (i) {
        if ($(this).css('display') == "inline-block") {
            //inline block - do what you need to do
            $(this).css({'display':'inline', 'zoom':'1'});  
        }
    });
}

});​
```

example demo (faked IE7) http://jsfiddle.net/nevtn/5/

Answer (score 4):

If you add the style directly to the element you can filter like the following:

**Code1**

`$("[style*='inline-block']");`

But the code above will not get elements if the style is computed using css, this case you can  use the following.

**Code2**

```
$('*').filter(function() {
    return $(this).css('display') == 'inline-block';
});
```

So if I have the following html.

```
<div style="display: inline-block"></div>
<div class="someClass"></div>
```

`Code1` get only the first.
`Code2` get both.